# Masking a polars dataframe for complex operations

Tags: python, dataframe, python-polars

If I have a polars Dataframe and want to perform masked operations, I currently see two options:

```py
# create data
df = pl.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]], schema = ['a', 'b']).lazy()
# create a second dataframe for added fun
df2 = pl.DataFrame([[8, 6, 7, 5], [15, 16, 17, 18]], schema=["b", "d"]).lazy()

# define mask
mask = pl.col('a').is_between(2, 3)
```

### Option 1: create filtered dataframe, perform operations and join back to the original dataframe

```py
masked_df = df.filter(mask)
masked_df = masked_df.with_columns(  # calculate some columns
    [
        pl.col("a").sin().alias("new_1"),
        pl.col("a").cos().alias("new_2"),
        (pl.col("a") / pl.col("b")).alias("new_3"),
    ]
).join(  # throw a join into the mix
    df2, on="b", how="left"
)
res = df.join(masked_df, how="left", on=["a", "b"])
print(res.collect())
```

### Option 2: mask each operation individually

```py
res = df.with_columns(  # calculate some columns - we have to add `pl.when(mask).then()` to each column now
    [
        pl.when(mask).then(pl.col("a").sin()).alias("new_1"),
        pl.when(mask).then(pl.col("a").cos()).alias("new_2"),
        pl.when(mask).then(pl.col("a") / pl.col("b")).alias("new_3"),
    ]
).join(  # we have to construct a convoluted back-and-forth join to apply the mask to the join
    df2.join(df.filter(mask), on="b", how="semi"), on="b", how="left"
)

print(res.collect())
```

### Output:

```
shape: (4, 6)
┌─────┬─────┬──────────┬───────────┬──────────┬──────┐
│ a   ┆ b   ┆ new_1    ┆ new_2     ┆ new_3    ┆ d    │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---      ┆ ---       ┆ ---      ┆ ---  │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ f64      ┆ f64       ┆ f64      ┆ i64  │
╞═════╪═════╪══════════╪═══════════╪══════════╪══════╡
│ 1   ┆ 5   ┆ null     ┆ null      ┆ null     ┆ null │
│ 2   ┆ 6   ┆ 0.909297 ┆ -0.416147 ┆ 0.333333 ┆ 16   │
│ 3   ┆ 7   ┆ 0.14112  ┆ -0.989992 ┆ 0.428571 ┆ 17   │
│ 4   ┆ 8   ┆ null     ┆ null      ┆ null     ┆ null │
└─────┴─────┴──────────┴───────────┴──────────┴──────┘
```

Most of the time, option 2 will be faster, but it gets pretty verbose and is generally harder to read than option 1 when any sort of complexity is involved.

Is there a way to apply a mask more generically to cover multiple subsequent operations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `struct` with an `unnest`

Your dfs weren't consistent between being lazy and eager so I'm going to make them both lazy

```
df.join(df2, on='b') \
    .with_columns(pl.when(mask).then(
        pl.struct([
            pl.col("a").sin().alias("new_1"),
            pl.col("a").cos().alias("new_2"),
            (pl.col("a") / pl.col("b").cast(pl.Float64())).alias("new_3")
        ]).alias('allcols'))).unnest('allcols') \
    .with_columns([pl.when(mask).then(pl.col(x)).otherwise(None) 
                for x in df2.columns if x not in df]) \
    .collect()
```

I think that's the heart of your question is how to write `when` `then` with multiple column outputs which is covered by the first `with_columns` and then the second `with_columns` covers the quasi-semi join value replacement behavior.

Another way you can write it is to first create a list of the columns in df2 that you want to be subject to the mask and then put those in the struct.  The unsightly thing is that you have to then exclude those columns before you do the `unnest`

```
df2_mask_cols=[x for x in df2.columns if x not in df.columns]
df.join(df2, on='b') \
    .with_columns(pl.when(mask).then(
        pl.struct([
            pl.col("a").sin().alias("new_1"),
            pl.col("a").cos().alias("new_2"),
            (pl.col("a") / pl.col("b").cast(pl.Float64())).alias("new_3")
        ] + df2_mask_cols).alias('allcols'))) \
    .select(pl.exclude(df2_mask_cols)) \
    .unnest('allcols') \
    .collect()
```

Surprisingly, this approach was fastest:

```
df.join(df2, on='b') \
    .with_columns([
            pl.col("a").sin().alias("new_1"),
            pl.col("a").cos().alias("new_2"),
            (pl.col("a") /pl.col("b").cast(pl.Float64())).alias("new_3")
        ]) \
    .with_columns(pl.when(mask).then(pl.exclude(df.columns))).collect()
```

Comment: After running some tests, it appears that the fastest option was the one you edited out, where the computations are performed first and the mask is only used to clear the masked rows *ex post*. I assume, however, that performance would vary greatly, depending on the data types, the properties of the masked rows and the computations.

Comment: @DataWiz that's pretty surprising...guess I'll edit it back in.

Answer (score 6):

You can avoid the boiler plate by applying your mask to your operations in a helper function.

```
def with_mask(operations: list[pl.Expr], mask) -> list[pl.Expr]:
    return [
        pl.when(mask).then(operation)
        for operation in operations
    ]

res = df.with_columns(
    with_mask(
        [
            pl.col("a").sin().alias("new_1"),
            pl.col("a").cos().alias("new_2"),
            pl.col("a") / pl.col("b").alias("new_3"),
        ],
        mask,
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks - I was thinking along the lines of list comprehensions too, and you spelled it out for me. Any ideas for the join?

Comment: This is really nice looking.  Do you know if the lazy optimizer is able to spot the repeated when mask and only perform it once or will it repeat that operation for all the columns?