# How can I edit a polars dataframe in place on a subset of rows that I am filtering according to some condition?

Tags: python-polars

How can I edit a dataframe in place on a subset of rows that I am filtering according to some condition?

So I have an example like this:

```py
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "a": [0, 1, 2, 3],
        "b": [0.5, 4, 10, 13],
        "c": ["foo", "foo", "foo", "foo"],
    }
)
```

and I want to replace the value in col `c` with `baz`, but only if the value in col `a` is `1`.

I can select the row with `filter` and edit that with `with_columns`, but then I have a new df.

```py
df.filter(
    pl.col("a") == 1
).with_columns(
    pl.col("c").str.replace("foo", "baz")
)
```

How do I get back the original df, with the modified row?

```
a    b    c
i64    f64    str
0    0.5    "foo"
1    4.0    "baz"
2    10.0    "foo"
3    13.0    "foo"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [`pl.when`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.when.html):

```py
df.with_columns(
    pl.when(pl.col("a").eq(1)).then(pl.col("c").str.replace("foo", "bar")).otherwise(pl.col("c"))
)

shape: (4, 3)
┌─────┬──────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ b    ┆ c   │
│ --- ┆ ---  ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ f64  ┆ str │
╞═════╪══════╪═════╡
│ 0   ┆ 0.5  ┆ foo │
│ 1   ┆ 4.0  ┆ bar │
│ 2   ┆ 10.0 ┆ foo │
│ 3   ┆ 13.0 ┆ foo │
└─────┴──────┴─────┘
```

Comment: I didn't know about `pl.when`, it's exactly what I needed, thanks!

Comment: @ThCP When you get to wanting to do when/then with multiple columns being impacted see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75471704/masking-a-polars-dataframe-for-complex-operations/75477135#75477135

Comment: @DeanMacGregor thanks for the link, that might be useful later.